# How to find $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{ a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

f:$\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable at $x=a$ the we are to evaluate the following:-
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}$$
My approach:-
$$\frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}=x^na^n\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x^n}-\frac{f(a)}{a^n}}{x-a}$$
Let
$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$
then$$x^na^n\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x^n}-\frac{f(a)}{a^n}}{x-a}=x^na^n\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$$
so that $$\lim_{x \to a}x^na^n\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=(\lim_{x \to a}x^na^n)g'(a)=a^{2n} \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)/x^n)$$
$$=a^{2n}\left(\frac{x^nf'(x)-nx^{n-1}f(x)}{x^{2n}}\right)_{x=a}=a^nf'(a)-na^{n-1}f(a)$$
Is my attemplt correct?

Comment: Try setting $x-a=h$

Comment: Are you a physicist? They have a talent for making math errors and getting the right answer anyway. Your only error is in the case $a=0$ where your division by $a^n$ is not valid. But your final formula is valid for $a=0$ and $n>0$ and even when  $a=0, n=1$ with the often-used (but cautiously-used) convention that $0^0=1$.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule seems quite efficient here.  - Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Quotient Rule idea is good, and is carried out very well. The only problem is that it does not work in the case $a=0$.  But that case is easily dealt with separately.

A simpler approach is to note that
$$a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)=(a^n f(x)-a^nf(a))-(x^nf(a)-a^nf(a)).$$

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote was for.

Comment: What's wrong with this? This is exactly how I would do it. The first term gives you $a^n f'(a)$ and the second gives you $f(a)((x^n)'|_{x=a}) = f(a)na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way  could be Taylor expansion around $x=a$ 
$$x^n=a^n+n a^{n-1} (x-a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$
$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ Then $$a^n f(x)-x^nf(a)=(x-a) \left(a^n f'(a)-n  a^{n-1}f(a)\right)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$